# Send exception to Caller method in c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Hello guys i'm working on Database  assignment in this i have one windows form and one class that i use to connect database and to execute queries and non-queries.

Question: I m using Post-Message label which inform only when "Product added successfully".but when i send wrong-data which can occur exception in executeNonQuery() in database class and after catching this exception and showing Error in message box.Control goes back to caller and it prints lblPostMsg in both cases which is "Product has been added successfully".
I want that when exception occur in database class i can stop executing rest of the code or if there is way that exception in calling method can be caught by caller method.

below is Code of windows Form button

```
 private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            con = new DbConnection();
            con.SqlQuery("INSERT INTO products VALUES(@products_ID,@products_Name)"); 
            con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products_ID", txtProID.Text);
            con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products_Name", txtProName.Text);
            try
            {
                con.ExecuteNonQueryF();

                this.categoriesTableAdapter1.Fill(this.purchasemasterDS.categories);
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
                lblPostMsg.Show();
                lblPostMsg.Text = "Product has been added successfully";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                con.CloseCon();
            }
    }
```

This code is from dbclass

```
public void ExecuteNonQueryF()
    {
        try
        {
            _con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex);

        }
```

Comment: You handle the exception in `ExecuteNonQueryF`. As far as `btnInsert_Click` is concerned, there was no exception. If you don't want that, don't handle the exception in `ExecuteNonQueryF`.

Answer (score 3):

you are catching, handling, and suppressing the `Exception` in `ExecuteNonQueryF`:

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex);    
}
```

Though this handles the `Exception` by showing the message, it causes the code to continue executing; the `Exception` won't be raised to the caller.

If you add `throw` after your `MessageBox.Show` is executed, the `Exception` will be raised to the caller and execution stops.

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception " + ex);
    throw;
}
```

Another option is to completely remove that `try-catch` in `ExecuteNonQueryF`  - letting the caller (your `button` `onclick` method) handle the `Exception`.

Comment: I have written some code in catch block in case of exception i want to show msg in that code. When i send wrong data to `con.ExecuteNonQueryF();` it stopped inside at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` after removing `try-catch`,-- is there way that i can show msg written in `btn_click` `try-catch` block

Comment: yes, leave just like you did the MessageBox.show in your catch. But then you need to throw the exception again, for the caller - otherwise, the exception will be considered "handled" and the code will continue executing

Answer (score 0):

you need to throw an explicit exception in ExecuteNonQuery's catch block like 
throw new Exception(ex)

and then in calle's catch block you need to write "return" to return from function. This will stop furter execution of function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Exception` will be raised to the caller and **execution stops**, then you must use `throw` at the last line of your catch block.

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    /*
      write your desire code. then throw
    */
    throw;
}
```